# AJAX is not working for me

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send AJAX but it is not working. Could someone please clarify what it is I am doing wrong or not doing. Just trying to figure this out.

FIRST PAGE.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-grn" id="scaleButton">Button</a></div>
<input class="form-control" name="cartID" id="cartID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $order['clientid'] ;?>">
    <p id="edit_box"></p>
<script>

$("#scaleButton").click(function()  { 
var cartID = "hello"
var second = "second";

///////// AJAX //////// AJAX //////////
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'testing1234.php',
        data: {first:cartID,second:second},
        success: function( response ){
            alert('yay ajax is done.');
            $('#edit_box').html(response);//this is where you populate your response
        }//close succss params
    });//close ajax
///////// AJAX //////// AJAX //////////
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

SECOND PAGE

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$first = $_POST['first'];
$second = $_POST['second'];
$third = $_POST['third'];


echo $second; 
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `does not work` is obvious, otherwise you wouldn't be asking a question. Try some debugging 101: check your browser developer tools console and network tabs for any signs of errors. Does the request get sent? Is there a response? add an `error:` handler to the $.ajax and log the error response

Comment: You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: "it does not work" in **NOT** an error message ! what do you mean ? no result ? wrong result ? an error ? we cannot guess what is printed on your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it's just a syntax issue. You forgot to close the click event with an ending parenthesis. This kind of problem can be easily avoided by using a text editor with linting. There are many out there, like Sublime Text, Atom, etc. Or as suggest in comment, open up developer console in your browser to check for any errors/warning.